# Best way to break a string in java

Tags: java, string

I need to construct a string in java on the client side and send it to the server to decode it.

I need the `client name` and whether he want to register or not (`"Subscribe"` or `"Unsubscribe"`).

I'm implementing it using hashmap, the client name is the key and a class with client data as the value.

I'm using `UDP`.

So what is the best way you think I should use for the encoding and decoding the request?

Thanks.

Comment: This is better suited for Programmers, as it is a white-board question rather a specific code question.

Answer (score 2):

Use JSON:

```
{"client-name": "cow", "action":"subscribe"}
```

Comment: Well, I don't think I need something to complected, it's for an assignment at school.

Comment: This is as simple as it gets.

Comment: I thought of maybe a nice string method to do something of this sort...

Comment: Okay, so how do u use it exactly? can I get a reference please? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could use any of the already available formats:

- [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) - as mentioned already in a response
- [YAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML)
- [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML)

If any of them seem to heavy-weight for you. You could make a simple custom format just for your application. But if I would be in your shoes I would go with with JSON, as you mentioned is 'just' a school assignment, so you should learn something.

Good luck